# NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' : Angular Modular Federation

Tags: angular, webpack, micro-frontend, angular-module-federation

NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' (used in the 'HomeComponent' component template).
If the 'ngIf' is an Angular control flow directive, please make sure that either the 'NgIf' directive or the 'CommonModule' is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.

MFE- Exposed - HomeModule

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    AngularMaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedComponentsModule,
    LanguageTranslateModule,
    NumericOnlyModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    ToolTipmatModule

  ],
```

While Trying in shell Application giving this error

MFE is an Angular 13

Shell is an Angular 14

Comment: share a stackblitz withe the issue replicated!

Comment: Did you try to just stop and start your project again?

Comment: @paranaaan yes tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was CommonModule

issue importing commonmodule and removing BrowserModule worked!!

Comment: Even after removing BrowerModule from shell and remote didn't worked for me